# Creating a Javascript Object Which Does Nothing

Tags: javascript, mocking

As a somewhat hacky method of disabling functionality, I came up with the idea of using some javascript like this:

```
//fakefrob.js
var frob = function () {
    return {
        myFunc: function(){},
        myFunc1: function(){},
        myFunc2: function(){return 2;},
        myFunc3: function(){},
        myFunc4: function(){}
    };
}();
```

In this example, the real frob has implementations of these functions.  Obviously this is a hack (the functions mostly do nothing or have placeholder return values).  If I add foobar to realfrob.js, I must add an empty implementation of foobar to fakefrob.js.  Is there a way (ideally without using a library) to write fakefrob.js such that `frob.foobar` acts like foobar was defined as `function(){};`, without actually adding foobar to fakefrob.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [T.J. Crowder suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314074/18192),  [supported browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=proxy) can use a [proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to accomplish this:

```
var frob = new Proxy({}, {get: function(){return function(){}}})
```

How this works:
This creates a proxy which intercepts all property getters, replacing the result with an empty function.  Normally, a proxy object is used to to intercept and eventually forward calls to our target (here, the target is `{}`).  However, this code blindly returning an empty function, completely ignoring the target.

Comment: Note that the proxy function could accept the original target, if we wanted to throw exceptions when the name did not exist.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way (ideally without using a library) to write fakefrob.js such that `frob.foobar` acts like foobar was defined as `function(){};`, without actually adding foobar to fakefrob.js?

You mean, a catch-all property, mapped to a no-op function? No, JavaScript doesn't (currently) have catch-all properties at all. (I believe some mechanism for them *is* being considered, as part of the proxy stuff coming down the pike at some stage.)

If you have access to the real `frob` in your code, though, your `fakefrob` can be generated completely automatically:

```
// Assumes `frob` already exists
(function() {
    var mock;
    var name;

    // Build the mock, with a function for each function
    // on the real object.
    mock = {};
    for (name in frob) {
        if (typeof frob[name] === "function") {
            mock[name] = function() { };
        }
    }

    // Replace the original    
    frob = mock;
})();
```

And of course, if you wanted to copy the non-function properties, you could do that at the same time.

Note that I intentionally did *not* include `hasOwnProperty` in the loop above, as I assume you want your mock to include functions even if `frob` inherits them from a prototype.

If `frob` inherits some functions and you wanted your mock to exhibit the same `hasOwnPropety` behavior for them as the original frob, you can get more creative:

```
// Assumes `frob` already exists
(function() {
    var mock;
    var mockProto;
    var name;

    function FakeFrob() {
    }

    mockProto = FakeFrob.prototype;

    // Build the mock, with a function for each function
    // on the real object.
    mock = new FakeFrob();
    for (name in frob) {
        if (typeof frob[name] === "function") {
            if (frob.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                mock[name] = function() { };
            }
            else {
                mockProto[name] = function() { };
            }
        }
    }

    // Replace the original    
    frob = mock;
})();
```

Now, if the original `frob` had its own `foo` (`frob.hasOwnProperty("foo")` is `true`) but an inherited `bar` (`frob.hasOwnProperty("bar")` is `false`), `hasOwnProperty` on your mock would say exactly the same thing.

Comment: `if (typeof realFrob[name] === "function") {` i think should be `if (typeof realFrob[name] !== "function") {` right, because realFrob[name] does not exist?

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu: The purpose of the loop is to create properties on `mock` with the same names as the properties on `realFrob` that refer to functions, so `===` rather than `!==`.